# Flow Scheduled Path isn't working as expected

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I have a Flow on Account which has two paths:

1. Run Immediately
2. Run after 1 minute of Account's Last Modified Date

In the first run, it runs regular business logic.

In the second run, there's a decision element which checks for 1 checkbox field and if it's `TRUE`, then it will call a future apex method and marks the checkbox back to `FALSE`.

So when I update that checkbox field to `TRUE` for a bunch of records using dataloader, the expectation is that:

1. The checkbox field on each Account is marked true - *Working as expected*
2. Regular flow logic is executed - *Working as expected*
3. The flow interview is scheduled to run after 1 min - *Working as expected*
4. The future apex is executed after 1 min - **This happens only on the first record of the list of scheduled interviews**
5. The checkbox field on each Account is marked false - *Working as expected*

I was under the impression that the flow will execute the future apex for each Account record, am I missing something here? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll almost bet that your invocable apex is not bulkified - and it is only handling the [0]th element of its input request arg (which is a list, each element corresponding to an interview in the transaction)

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Thank you! Turn this comment to an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll almost bet that your invocable apex is not bulkified - and it is only handling the [0]th element of its input request arg (which is a list, each element corresponding to an interview in the transaction)

For example, if your invocable looks like this

```
@InvocableMethod (..)
public static void doWork(Id[] ids) {
   doFutureWork(ids[0]);
}

@Future
private static void doFutureWork(Id id) {
  .. do async stuff
}
```

A transaction, such as Data Loader, will present multiple Flow Interviews. When each interview reaches the invocable apex point, the interview pauses until all the transaction's interviews reach that point.

- Then, a single call to the invocable Apex is made, passing a list of arguments where argument[0] corresponds to interview[0], argument[1] corresponds to interview[1].
- So, the reason why only the first data loader update calls the future is because the invocable is not bulkified - it is only handling request[0] (i.e.. interview[0])

How you bulkify this is up to you. Ultimately, since a Data Loader transaction could be 200 interviews, the future method should be bulkified as well